# Use of & and () in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Following command is taken from  a shell script,

```
( ST1=`date`; class_name -C file.cfg    $* > output.log 2>&1; echo START: $ST1 >> output2.log; echo END: `date` >> output2.log) &
```

1. In above shell script, there are few commands, seperated by `;` inside `()`. 
   Google search says that it is used for array, but the shell script is not assigning the output to anything. What probably could be the use of `()`?
2. What is use of `&` at end?

Comment: Can you post the whole script, its kind of vague right now.

Comment: it has 1000s of LOC and i dont have permissions to post that :(

Comment: You could at least post the snippet involving parentheses.

Comment: @chepner I have posted it. Please check

Comment: @snyder I cant post whole script. Just see the code inside block.

Answer (score 1):

> And there are few commands, seperated by ; inside (). Google search says that it is used for array, but the shell script is not assigning the output to anything. What probably could be the use of ()?

`()` is just like a block of code in programming. Values set to variables will not affect to the variables in global.

For example, see the following sh script:

```
a=1;  
(
    a=2; #This value is for a in local ()
    echo $a; #print 2
)  
echo $a; #print 1
```

It will print:

```
2
1
```